# Team foundation server's automated build is not getting the latest code

Tags: tfs

I have setup a build controller etc and the builds were failing, I have fixed these now and the build failed properly - as in because of an error.

I have fixed the error and checked the code back in but now the code is not being extracted, although sometimes one folder of many is.

I have deleted the code from the build machine and requeued a build but it keeps failing.  It complains that it cannot find the solution that I specified as the build solution.

I have checked the check box to build even if nothing has changed.
Have I missed a setting somewhere for extracting the code?

TFS version is 2012 Express
Visual Studio version is 2010 Professional

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: Good point, have updated the question

Comment: Is your work-space defined correctly in your build definition?

Comment: I believe so - it worked previously, before it was complaining that the build failed (paths issue) and eventually that there was a wrong include.  Now it does not get the files out.  Perhaps I have knocked it out of step somewhere

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Also are you using a msbuild .proj file or the default xaml build?

Comment: Aha - the clean command was set to None ... which is odd as it sometimes downloaded a directory or two.  Now I have set it to 'All' the files are being downloaded!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several properties in your build definition you can check. I would start with setting the "Clean Workspace" to All to ensure the correct code is being pulled down and built.

There are other checks you can look at as well like the agent set for the build and the "GetVersion" property. Check the below link out. It should be able to help you in more detail.

[Define a Build Process that is Based on the Default Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#projects)

Comment: That is it!  Clean was set to 'None'!  Thanks

Comment: Nice. Glad it was an easy fix.

Comment: In TFS2013 the "Clean Workspace" property in the default template is a `true|false` setting. However, I have mine set to `true` and am still having issues with my code not updating.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue recently with TFS 2012.  I think it boils down to this:

In the lastest build definition files, it appears that it performs a `Clean` task **before** updating the workspace.  This means that if you do something that causes the `Clean` part of the build to fail, it will never download the new files in order to fix it.

Recently, I was making big changes to my build file and inevitably made a lot of mistakes, I found that if one of these mistakes caused the `Clean` to break, I had to go onto the Build server and change the file manually to get it working again.

Does this sound like it might be the same issue?

Comment: It might be.  I have deleted the code from the build machine's folder and I keep getting the error that it cannot find the solution file that I specified as a build target.  Did you get this?  When you say that you had to change the file manually, which file are you referring to?

Comment: It sounds to me like its the same issue.  In my case, I was editing build files.  I essentially broke the build file so the build started failing.  When I fixed the build file and checked it in, the build server would not download the fix as it would fail on the CLEAN which happened before the get.  I ended up manually editing the build file on the build server.

Comment: What did you change in the build file?

Comment: What I changed in the build file isn't really relevant.  The point is that if the source / msbuild files are in a state where the `Clean` target will fail, then I believe that the build server will not get the latest version.

Comment: It does not sound like your build file is wrong. It appears that it cannot find your solution file to build. I would double check that it is being pulled down and then look at your build.

Comment: Clean was set to 'None'!  Now I have set it to all it is downloading the files!

Comment: Pleased you got it sorted.

Comment: I definitely broke the Clean target on a project file, and was only able to identify that that was why I wasn't getting new code on the build server through this answer.  I changed the Clean Workspace value from "Outputs" to "All" and it got rid of the problem.  I don't know why that worked.